# Convert DateTime to Date Doctrine php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, doctrine

Hello i'm working with Doctrine (php) and mysql.

I need to convert my `Datetime` field to a `Date`.
But Doctrine date manipulator function are rare ...

I've try some manipulation with `DATE_ADD` and `DATE_DIFF` but without succes.

The purpose is to GROUP BY Date to display statistics per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `GROUP BY DATE(your_column)`.

Comment: Result : [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected known function, got 'DATE'

Comment: here is my request :
SELECT DATE(s.time), COUNT(b)
                        FROM CSC\SupportBundle\Entity\Requete b
                        JOIN b.status s
                        GROUP BY DATE(s.time)

Comment: You can only do that using raw SQL, see: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1236

Comment: [On a sidenote: what a worthless system if you can't even cast to date...]

Comment: The issue has been fixed, see http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1236.